# touchstart and touchend events does not work on Webview in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, dom-events, android-scrollview

I have multiple webviews inside scrollview in Android. This is one of the prime requirement of my app. I am loading html with Javascript inside webviews. The Javascript contains a button which implements touchstart and touchend events. All my webviews are rendering fine. But the problem is few of the webviews does not fire touchstart and touchend events on the button. This is happening randomly with webviews. Also the links on those webviews are not tappable.

I have no idea why this is happening. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: I noticed the same thing... have to scroll (or put the image right at the bottom of the view) before it'll trigger the touchstart. I HATE ANDROID'S WEBVIEW SO MUCH !!

Comment: I have a phonegap application that's doing the same thing right now. It's very random as to when it occurs. I'm on a Nexus 7 running Android 4.4.2 and the only solution I've found is to change the events from touchstart to click. Which is not very ideal for our users.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer:
[Android - JavaScript : touchstart event not fired until zoom or scroll the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477550/android-javascript-touchstart-event-not-fired-until-zoom-or-scroll-the-page)

This got things working for me.

You might also want to check out the first answer here, regarding using e.preventDefault():
[touchend event doesn't work on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987706/touchend-event-doesnt-work-on-android)

Good luck!